# IntelliJ import subfolder as project

Tags: intellij-idea

Having a code structure like below which contains documentation at the root level how can I TELL IDEA to import the `Code/spark` subfolder as a project?

```
.
├── Code
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── bar
│   │   └── baz
│   └── spark
│       ├── build.sbt
│       ├── common
│       ├── job1
│       ├── project
│       ├── run_application
│       ├── sbt
│       ├── scalastyle-config.xml
│       └── version.sbt
├── Docs
```

Comment: Have you tried to add new module in "Project Structure | Modules" pointing to "spark" directory?

Comment: This does not seem to work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better: use a proper build tool like gradle and then apply https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to add Content Root, go to Project Structure settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>), select your module, then on the right panel click **Add Content Root** and select Docs folder. Then you can select it and mark as part of the Module, for documentation I believe it should be **Resources**.

Comment: In my case I had a conflict error and i was not able to find how to remove the current cotent root: "To remove a content root, select it in the right-hand pane and then click Cancel next to it. Confirm the deletion. Note that the corresponding folder won't be physically deleted."